# How do flap track guides work?

Tags: aircraft-design, flaps

I am planning to build a large-scale LEGO airlier with most parts functional. Doing a little looking at pictures and research I see that commercial airliners have an underwing body that houses the flap track guides. How do they work mechanically?

Comment: A [video of Boeing 737 Flaps extension and retraction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cld62K4ntbk) ---- A [drawing](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Flaps_Mechanism_B787_A320.png) --- The Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flap_%28aeronautics%29).

Comment: @mins I want to know how the mechanics of it works so I can replicate it with LEGO.

Comment: You won't have many freedom to accurately replicate the actual mechanism (there are many different according to the aircraft model). Maybe [this will help](http://www.technicbricks.com/2013_11_01_archive.html). Else the drawing (right side) linked above show you the track.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are different ways of moving flaps. The trivial case where they rotate around a hinge point which lies within the airfoil contour does not increase wing area. Fowler-type, backward-moving flaps are possible in three general ways:

1. Douglas flap: Here the flap rotates around a single hinge line which lies substantially below the airfoil contour. As the name suggests, this is used on many Douglas Commercial aircraft.

[image: Douglas flap]

Douglas flap, left: retracted ([source](http://www.airlinercafe.com/aviation_articles/dc9_guide/image159.jpg)); right: extended ([source](https://www.metabunk.org/data/attachments/5/5876-bc601fd95a5bfc332bf35c0fd675d23b.jpg)). Their long and narrow supports make them easy to recognize.

2. Four- or five-bar linkages: These are mechanically more complex, but enable a more compact mechanism. As their name suggests, four or five linkages are connected with bearings and enable a more complex movement. The drawing and the animated GIF below are taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkage_(mechanical)#Mobility) and show the mobility m which increases with the number of joints. This would be my recommendation for a Lego model; just make sure that the forward bar is longer than the rear bar - this will give you a realistic movement of the flap.

[image: Linkage mobility]

Above: Linkage mobility (picture [source](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/05/Linkage_mobility.png)). Below: Four bar linkage (picture [source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:4_bar_linkage_animated.gif))

[image: four bar linkage]

3. Sliding block guide: Here you find real rails and rollers which move along them to enable the most complex and precise movement, even for multi-element flaps. While a four-bar linkage will have a continuously increasing ratio of deflection angle to backward shift, a sliding block guide makes it possible to set the deflection angle independent of the backward shift, and allows the biggest backward shift for a given size of the mechanism. See the Boeing 747 flap tracks below for an example.

[image: Boeing 747 flap tracks]

Boeing 747 flap tracks (picture [source](http://www.billzilla.org/747flaptrack.jpg)). Note that the upper block is supporting the first flap segment and the lower block the second. Actuation is via a spindle; the linkage in the lower left corner is actually the mechanism for moving the flap fairing.